# How to set an icon to "SelectEntity" form?

Tags: c#, autodesk-vault

I'm using VDF library of autodesk api and use 'select entity' dialog to select a file from vault. Everything is fine except one thing - I don't know how to set an icon to this form, therefore dialog has the default icon of windows form. I'm using code below to call 'SelectEntity' dialog. And so, my question is How to set an icon to selectentity dialog?

```
        SelectEntitySettings settings = new SelectEntitySettings();
        var result = VDF.Vault.Forms.Library.SelectEntity(Connection, settings);
```

[image: I marked that I want to change in this form]

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon, in visual studio open "Form1.cs" and in the "Form1.cs[Design]".

Once open you can select the properties of the form, by clicking the background of the form.

The "Properties" windows will show a list of properties that can be assigned. Move down the "Icon" and select a path to a .ICO you want to use.

If you don't already have an .ico file there are online free tools to create it.